# Custom command in npm tfs 2015

Tags: tfs, npm, build, tfs-2015, vnext

I'm creating vNext builds using tfs 2015 and I want to run custom command in npm task. The command - npm lint. During build I have error that this command is unknow.

[image]

this is how looks my step:

[image]

If it's a command like start/stop/install then everything is ok.

How I can customize this step?

Comment: How do you implement the custom command? Have you tried with npm run lint?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I just forgot to write answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only one what I added it's command "run" before lint. So final command will be "run lint".

Answer (score 0):

Just as error described, npm lint is not a **cli commands**.  The detail list of cli commands please refer [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/).

It's not support to run it with [npm build task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/package/npm) in TFS build  definition.